# Extra separator after MdiWindowListItem when no child windows are open

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, mdi, mdichild

I have an MDI application. I have a `ToolStripMenuItem` labeled "Window" that is set as the `MdiWindowListItem` of my main `MenuStrip`. The Window menu has a couple of items, such as "Cascade" and "Arrange Icons".

When I run my application, the Window menu ends neatly with my "Arrange Icons" item. As expected, when I open one or more MDI child forms, these are automatically appended after a `ToolStripSeparator`. When I close all of the child forms, they disappear as expected from the "Window" menu, however the `ToolStripSeparator` remains. I would have expected the menu to return to its original state, i.e. without the separator.

As it stands, the separator is automatically added but not automatically removed. I could try to programmatically eliminate the extra separator, of course, but I don't see anyone else complaining about this, which leads me to suspect that it might be happening because I did something wrong. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your own ToolStripSeparator menu item after your "Arrange Icons" menu items and set the Visible property to false.

When opening an MDI child form, make it visible:

```
  Form f = new Form();
  f.Text = "Test Form";
  f.MdiParent = this;
  f.FormClosed += ChildClosed;
  f.Show();
  ts.Visible = true;
```

Then in the ChildClosed method:

```
void ChildClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate 
                      { ts.Visible = (this.MdiChildren.Count() > 0); }
                  );
}
```

Comment: That gets the job done, but the standard behaviour still baffles me. The menu automatically adds child forms, and again removes them. It automatically adds a separator, but it doesn't remove it. Where is the logic?

Comment: By the way, why is it necessary to use BeginInvoke here? I tried just setting the value of `ts.Visible` straight and it didn't work properly. Is it to wait for the form to update its child list?

Comment: @Stephan The `MdiChildren.Count` won't be zero until *after* the last child form is closed.  In the Closed event, the child form isn't quite gone yet.  `BeginInvoke` is a simple little way of telling the program to run a piece of code after the current procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`ts.Visible = (this.MdiChildren.Count() > 1)` 
in the closed event of the child is enough. No need for a BeginInvoke

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As indicated in my comment on @LarsTech's answer, I have tried setting `Visible` without the `BeginInvoke`, but I found that this failed to hide the separator when the child is closed.